# Quando usar classes estáticas?

Tags: php, classes, instanciar-objeto

Por exemplo dentro de um framework, devo utilizar classes estáticas apenas para recursos como cálculo de frete, geradores de formulário, upload de mídia? ou por exemplo posso utilizar uma classe estática para o Router|Bootstrap do MVC? isso teria alguma vantagem?

Comment: Classes estática ou método/função estático?